# How to isolate the first value of every multi index using pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7

If I have a Pandas Dataframe like this:

[image]

How do I isolate each time's first value such that I get a Pandas Dataframe like this:[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
df=df.groupby(['Time'],sort= True).max()
```

Something like this will work and keeps the maximum value - is there a reason that you want to keep the first value?

Answer (score 0):

Slice by negating where the first level of the index is duplicated.

```
df[~df.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated()]
```

#### Sample Data

```
import pandas as pd
df = pd.DataFrame({'A': list('aaabbbcccdd'), 'B': list('12345672345'),
                   'C': [1,12,13,14,15,1,16,16,17,2,23]}).set_index(['A', 'B'])

      C
A B    
a 1   1
  2  12
  3  13
b 4  14
  5  15
  6   1
c 7  16
  2  16
  3  17
d 4   2
  5  23

df[~df.index.get_level_values(0).duplicated()]

      C
A B    
a 1   1
b 4  14
c 7  16
d 4   2
```